# PHP Outputting Key Names From Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an `array`:

```
$cats = array(
  'guitars' => array (
    'electric-guitars',
    'acoustic-guitars',
    'bass',
    'electro-acoustic',
    'effects-fx-pedals',
    'guitar-amps',
    'classical-guitars',
    'guitar-recording',
    'folk',
    'cases-stands',
    'guitar-care',
    'guitar-accessories'
  ),
  'drums',
  'keyboards',
  'studio',
  'computer',
  'dj-pa',
  'brass',
  'accessories'
);
```

And I'm trying to output the top level keys so it outputs the following:

```
guitars
drums
keyboards
studio
computer
dj-pa
brass
accessories
```

I'm using this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($cats as $cat => $cat_name) {
  echo '<div>' . $cat_name . '</div>';
}
```

But this instead outputs:

```
Array
drums
keyboards
studio
computer
dj-pa
brass
accessories
```

If anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to output the value, rather than the key. When you use `foreach(... as ... => ...)`, the syntax is `foreach($array as $key => $value)`. Your variable names are backwards. Also, you need to use `is_array()` to figure out what the output is, because you are inconsistent in your use of key names versus values:

```
foreach($cats as $cat_name => $cat) {
    if(is_array($cat)) { // guitars
        echo '<div>' . $cat_name . '</div>';
    }
    else { // the other values have numeric keys
        echo '<div>' . $cat . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Output (tags omitted for readability):

```
guitars
drums
keyboards
studio
computer
dj-pa
brass
accessories
```

Comment: this will echo `guitars
0
1
2
3
4
5
6`

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Thanks; I missed the inconsistent use of key names above.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't know that about the order in which the syntax is written in, thanks :) but this echoes `guitars 0 1 2 3 4 5 6`, any ideas on to fix this?

Comment: @Ed Cottrell - I made the same mistake but tested before I posted :p

Comment: Already fixed; please see above. Also, whoever downvoted: the edited code works.